# Creating TIN using R

Tags: r, tin

I have some rasters (.tif) and need to identify sinks and calculate TINs for sink volume calculations in R. I have done this before using ArcGIS but for various reasons I want to use R now. I'm not so familiar with R packages, so maybe someone has a good idea on how to get it done.

So far, I've found the `lidR` package which only uses .las-data and I'm not sure if it is possible to transform .tif-files to .las format.

Also, I've found the `RSAGA` package, but unfortunately this needs the path to an existing SAGA-installation which doesn't exist (I am working on a Linux server without a SAGA installation).

TINs are mentioned on the `sf` website (https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html), but there is no explanation on how to create them with `sf`-functions.

Are there other possibilities to calculate sink volume in rasters?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. You want to triangulate a raster?

Comment: I am sorry for the unclarity. But you are right: I want to identify sinks in my DEM and triangulate them to then calculate their volume. In ArcGIS this is pretty easy using ```sink``` , ```fill``` and ```TIN``` tools, but in R it seems more complicated.

Comment: I have effectively used the `deldir` package to create large TIN's.

Comment: I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIN`s and some of the other simple feature geometry classes are not well supported in `sf` at the moment. You can create them, but not do much else. For example (drawing from the WKT examples on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) :

```
> tin = st_as_sfc("TIN (((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)), ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 0 0 0)))")
> plot(tin)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

So there's no `plot` method for TINs.

You can get to the individual triangles, but:

```
> tin[[1]][[2]]
TRIANGLE Z ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 0 0 0))
> plot(tin[[1]][[2]])
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

there's no plot method for triangles either.

I think you should look into other software for this - and try and persuade the server admin to install SAGA or GRASS and interface with those - they have the best code for dealing with DEMs in this way.

Comment: I was afraid someone might say something like that. But thanks for the clarification! I guess I have to convince IT so that I can use ```RSAGA```.